# program terminate after using try catch block in switch statement

Tags: java, switch-statement, try-catch

the following code terminate after try catch block catches exception.its not allowing me to make choice from the menu option. so my question is what changes do i have to make on this code so that i can loop back so that i can get user input again.

```
    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Modify modifyObj = new Modify();

            int choice = 0 ;

           Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            //begin loop
            do {
                 try{

                //display menu

                System.out.println("Choose one option from following option available: ");
                System.out.println("0) Exit program. ");
                System.out.println("1) Create a Roster");
                System.out.println("2) Modify a Roster");
                System.out.println("3) Delete a Roster");



                choice = input.nextInt(); //gets user input 

                    switch (choice) {

                        case 1:
//code
                         break;


                        case 2:
    //code
                                break;

                        case 3:
                            //code
                           break;


                    }// end of switch statement
                    break;
                }//end oftry
                 catch(InputMismatchException inputMismatchException){
                    System.out.println("Enter integer  value between 0 and 7:"); 
                    continue;
                 }


            }while (choice!=0); //loop until user exit 0.

        }//end of main
    }// end of Main class
```

Comment: Why is there a `break;` after the conclusion of the `switch(choice)` block? Won't that kick you out of the loop?

Comment: that was typo in my code and i just changed still having same problem.

Comment: I suspect the answer by @Elliot addresses the problem in the case of the Exception. The presence of the extraneous `break` prevents repeated looping until one selected to exit.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `choice` isn't `0` before you `continue;`

```
catch(InputMismatchException inputMismatchException){
    System.out.println("Enter integer  value between 0 and 7:"); 
    choice = 1; // <-- not 0.
    continue;
}
```

**Note** that you *default* `choice` to an initial value of `0`.

You Could Use Methods

If you extracted your logic into one (or two) utility methods to display the menu and get the user's choice it would simplify things; something like

```
private static void showMenu() {
    System.out.println("Choose one option from following option available: ");
    System.out.println("0) Exit program. ");
    System.out.println("1) Create a Roster");
    System.out.println("2) Modify a Roster");
    System.out.println("3) Delete a Roster");
}

private static int getUserOption(Scanner input) {
    while (true) {
        showMenu();
        if (input.hasNextInt()) {
            int t = input.nextInt();
            switch(t) {
            case 0: case 1: case 2: case 3:
                return t;
            }
        } else {
            input.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Then your `main` could invoke it like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Modify modifyObj = new Modify();

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice;
    // begin loop
    do {
        choice = getUserOption(input);
        if (choice != 0) {
            System.out.printf("You chose %d.%n", choice);
        }
    } while (choice != 0); // loop until user enters 0.
}// end of main
```

Comment: There is a `break` after the switch. Is that not the cause rather than this?

Comment: @Gendarme Perhaps I'm foolish to believe OP about *the following code terminate after try catch block catches exception*.

Comment: when i  change choice to 1 my code is running infinitely.

Comment: Your `break` statements apply to the `switch`; if you want to `break` the loop add a label.

Comment: Or,  *better* extract your logic into methods and invoke them. See edit.

Comment: still it didnt fixed my problem ,my code is running infinately.

Comment: i have already solved it without using try catch method. but in this project i have to use try catch block.